# How to SSH into a server that is only addressable and accessible from jump host?

Tags: ssh

I can SSH the jump host server B from my local machine A via `ssh B`.

Server C is only addressable (has an address of C.internal) and accessible from B via `ssh C`.

How do I SSH into C directly from my local machine?

What would the SSH command and config file look like?

ssh config on A:

```
Host B
    User userB
    HostName B.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyB
```

ssh config on B:

```
Host C
  HostName C.internal
  User userC
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyC
```

Is it possible to do this without copying `~/.ssh/keyC` from host B to local machine A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, but none of which are "single command":

You could run an SSH command to B that just runs a second SSH command to C; you need to add the `-t` option to make it work for interactive SSH:

- `ssh -t hostB "ssh hostC"`
- `ssh -t hostB "ssh -t hostC htop"`
- `ssh hostB ssh hostC ls -la /etc`

If you want a way to SSH "directly" from A to C, you'll need some additional contraption to forward an ssh-agent connection *from B* to the local system (i.e. the opposite of what `ssh -A` would normally do).

1. SSH to host B, then start an ssh-agent at a manually-specified path. Use the SSH "stream forward" feature to allow local clients access the remote agent process:

   ```
   HostA$ ssh -t -L /tmp/agent:/tmp/agent HostB \
       "ssh-agent -a /tmp/agent sh -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyC && sleep infinity'"
   ```

   (The ssh/config option is `LocalForward`.)
2. As long as the above connection is running, you can connect from HostA to HostC using the regular ProxyJump configuration, using keys that only exist on HostB:

   ```
   HostA$ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/agent
   HostA$ ssh -J HostB HostC
   ```

   (The ssh/config options are `IdentityAgent` and `ProxyJump`.)

---

Another option is to copy `keyC` from B to A and store it *on secure hardware* such as a TPM chip or a smartcard (a Yubikey with PIV mode also counts). This allows using the key locally on machine A without the possibility of it being stolen.

(For TPM2.0 on Linux, you could go for either `tpm2-pkcs11` or `ssh-tpm-agent`; TPM2.0 on Windows could be used via PuTTY-CAC. For Yubikeys with PIV, there are PKCS#11 modules for both Windows and Linux. I'm using an eToken 5110 from Ebay. There's also a way to use FIDO2 keys with SSH, but it would require generating a new key.)

Comment: Thank you, I decided to just copy keyC from B to my local machine so that I can use the straightforward ProxyJump with only a single command. 

Answer (score 4):

You need a ssh_config file like global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or as user `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host B
  HostName 10.0.0.1
  User username_on_B
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_for_B
  ForwardAgent yes

# final destination
Host C
  HostName C.internal
  User your_username_on_C
  ProxyJump B
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_for_C
```

Now, from `A`, you can `ssh` `C`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried your answer with verbose output and found that the local machine doesn't have the private key to authenticate with host C (see my edited question) so this doesn't work. But C.internal seems to be able to resolve this this.

Comment: Check edited post to add ssh key

Comment: OP _could_ perhaps use `ssh -A hostB` and then do `ssh-add ~/ssh/keyC` to load the key from hostB into their local ssh-agent, but that technically still counts as copying it to the local machine, although I'd say it's a bit safer than transferring it as a file (since it only ever exists in the local machine's RAM).